# Solving for x in "xy + z ≡ 0 (mod k)"

Tags: algorithm, modulo

I need to solve for x in the congruence relation

> xy + z ≡ 0   (mod k)

where y, z, and k are known. (k may not be prime.)

Is there a better algorithm than just testing all values from 0 to k-1?

I tried using number theory, and got this:

> xy ≡ -z   (mod k)
>   x ≡ -z · (inverse(y)%k)   (mod k)

but I'm getting wrong results for some cases. For example, if k = 728, x = 272, y = 344, and z = 344, then the original relation holds (because 272·344+344 = 129·728) but the last one does not. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps  `((x*y)+z) mod k =0`  or  `(x*y)+z = 0 (mod k)` ?

Comment: There isn't really an ambiguity, appending `mod k` to a mathematical equation means you're talking about a congruence relations, not that an explicit "take remainder by k" operation ever takes place

Comment: Do we always have that `z` is a multiple of `gcd(y, k)` or was that just a coincidence?

Comment: @harold not always, but that may apply in some cases.

Comment: These things are kind of far in my head but here is why it does not work. An inverse exists if and only if x and k are coprime. In your case they are not. This means you have to rely on other means to solve the equation. There might be no or many solutions. For that you have to break k into its prime factorization and solve for these. The [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Generalization_to_non-coprime_moduli) then allows you to build back a result from these. Honnestly, I always end up confused as how to use it, but I know it's the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Your solution fails because
`The multiplicative inverse of “y modulo k” exists if and only if y and k are relatively prime (i.e., if gcd(y, k) = 1).` In the example that you chose `y` and `k` were not co-prime
Here is another way to solve the problem

> xy + z ≡ 0 (mod k) 
>  xy ≡ -z (mod k) 
>  xy ≡ -z + k (mod k) 
>   Let  k - z = b 
>   xy ≡ b (mod k)

Now you just need to solve linear congruence equation. 
Solving for your given example will look like

> x * 344 + 344 ≡ 0 (mod 728) 
>  x * 344 ≡ -344 (mod 728) 
>  x * 344 ≡ -344 + 728 (mod k) 
>   x * 344 ≡ 384 (mod 728)

Solving this first by **reducing** to x * 43  ≡ 48 (mod 91) , and then using **extended Euclidean algorithm** will give general form of solution as

> 90 + 91 * t 
>   Solutions for x less than 728 : 90, 181, 272, 363, 454, 545, 636, 727.

This way you can find all the possible solutions for x.

Comment: @user56036 If you reduce your example to  x * 43 ≡ 48 (mod 91) , where gcd(43, 91) is 1, then you will be able to find answer your way as well because after reduction 43 will have inverse modulo 91.